# Autodesk Forge - Specifying path to the file to upload

Tags: curl, autodesk-forge

I am working on a project in which I have to convert different file formats to .stl. I am using Autodesk Forge cloud software for this purpose and using rest APIs to communicate with it. More specifically, I have followed [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-to-obj/) tutorial and it works fine. In STEP 2 of [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/app-managed-bucket/) tutorial, the methodology to upload a file is demonstrated. The command is as below

```
curl -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/$BUCKETNAME/objects/$FILETOCONVERT" -X "PUT" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -T "$FILETOCONVERT"
```

I believe the first occurrence of FILETOCONVERT specifies the file name as it would be on the cloud bucket. The second occurrence is the file on the local system which has to be uploaded.

In case the file is in the same directory as the script, the code runs fine. However, is there any way I can provide path to the input file in the command below (which might be in a different directory)? I have tried replacing the second occurrence of "$FILETOCONVERT" to "/home/User/path/file.obj" but I get an HTTP Error for invalid command.

Does anyone know how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [cURL manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) the file paths are all in relative in their samples:

```
curl -T file.txt -u "domain\username:passwd"
```

Whether or not absolute paths are supported vary with specific implementation of cURL on your OS platform and is outside the scope of Forge services - you may try to PUT a file to another service with similar command to isolate the issue.

Alternatively give [symbolic links](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/) a go and see if cURL follows them.